# Choosing Option In Ajax-based Select2 From JS

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 4.0.0 for this project. A lot of the other comments and thoughts on this issue seem be for previous versions of select2, so I decided to post a new question.

I have a select2 on a page that can both create entries in the database and edit entries in the database. The select2 is populated dynamically by ajax after the user types a few letters and they can select a value. This works fine for creating entries when they need to select one.

On the same page, they can click existing entries to display further information and edit the entry in the same form. This also needs to update the select2 element with the correct selection text and update the select element that is backing the select2. Since this is normally done through ajax, the markup doesn't exist normally.

I've tried reading the documentation for select2, but I find it a bit disorganized. Does select2 provide any feature for accomplishing this? Do I need to create and update all the markup manually? I had looked at a dataAdapter, but I'm not sure if that is what I need or not.

HTML:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="entry" id="select_field" data-url="/entry/search"></select>
```

Code for the select2 element:

```js
$("#select_field").select2({
    placeholder: "Search",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        cache: true,
        delay: 250,
        method: 'POST',
        url: $("#select_field").data('url'),
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data,
            };
        },
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    templateSelection: function (record) {
        if (!record.id) { return record.text; }
        return record.title;
    },
    templateResult: function (record) {
        if (record.loading) { return record.text; }
        var markup = $("<div>").text(record.title);
        return markup.html();
    },
});
```